# can we use ID Token as an Access Token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, access-token, openid-connect

As I know an ID Token is like below :

```
{
  "iss": "http://YOUR_DOMAIN/",
  "sub": "authentication",
  "aud": "clien id",
  "exp": 1512285980,
  "iat": 1512280980,
  "name": "omid",
  "given_name": "omid",
  "family_name": "haghighatgoo",
  "gender": "male",
  "birthdate": "1987-10-31",
  "email": "a@b.com",

}
```

and an access token is like this :

```
{
  "iss": "https://YOUR_DOMAIN/",
  "sub": "authentication",
  "aud": [
    "api-identifier",
    "https://YOUR_DOMAIN/userinfo"
  ],
  "azp": "clientid",
  "exp": 1512285980,
  "iat": 1512280980,
  "scope": "profile email"
}
```

as it is obvious all parameters in access token can be in id token too. so why we should not use id token as an access token? I mean both of them could be handled by one token if JWT is used.

Answer (score 4):

OpenID connect builds on top of OAuth2 and adds the ID token as an extra feature. Neither OpenID nor OAuth2 states what the format of an access token should be (it doesn't have to be a JWT), so you should explain in your question why you say it has this format (i.e. which OpenID provider (OP) you are using). The access token can just as easily be an opaque reference to grant data which is stored on the OP (which also allows access to be revoked, for example).

To provide the simplest answer, you probably can't do this simply because your OP will reject the request if you do. The audience for the ID token is the client whereas the audience for the access token is the OP. They serve different purposes and will be encoded and validated differently.

The ID token is information for the client app to tell it who the authenticated user is. It will likely be signed with an asymmetric algorithm so that the client can validate it was issued by the OP.

The client app doesn't need to know the content of the access token at all or validate it. The token only needs to be understood and validated by the OP when it receives a request at the `userinfo` endpoint.